# Why isn't my ModelFormSet saving?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using a `ModelFormSet`, and I'm getting a `None` value for my instances. `POST` data is coming through; the form validates; and everything's great up until `instances = form.save(commit=False)`. What could be the origin of this?

```
    if request.POST:
            form = MembershipFormSet(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    instances = form.save(commit=False)
                    for instance in instances:
                            instance.user = request.user
                            instance.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('next_page')
            else:   
                    return HttpResponse(form.errors + request.POST.items())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if request.POST:
    formset = MembershipFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('next_page')
    else:   
        return HttpResponse(formset.errors + request.POST.items())
```

Your issue is here:

```
instances = form.save(commit=False)
```

The issue is, you need to extract the individual form objects, cast it to the object instance, and assign `user` to it. Where as in your code, `instances=form.save(...)` is not doing that.